# Retain Expanded Gridview on postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a master gridview where each row can be expanded to show a child gridview. 
The master grid loads with all children collapsed. 
I do the expanding/contracting of the child grids in javascript so its nice an quick when loaded.

The problem I have is that when the page does a post back (e.g. when the user clicks to sort one of the columns) all the child grids get set back to a collapsed state. I want the expanded/collapsed state to be remembered.

The examples I've found so far all seem to do the expanding/collapsing on the server side. 
But this seems really clunky and slow.

I'm thinking of trying to pass the expanaded/collapsed state of each row back to the server using a hidden field in each row of the master grid.

This hidden field would be set/cleared by the same JS routine which does the expanding/collapsing.

This seems like a good way to do it to me, but since I can't find any examples online I'm concerned I'm missing something???

Any reason not to do it using a hidden field?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, track state in a hidden field.  AJAX control toolkit does this for it's controls.  Hidden field is a common approach.  I'd highly recommend it, and that is the reason why you are experiencing this, because client mechanisms have no ability to "remember" preferences on postbacks, but hidden fields bridge that gap nicely.

Comment: Hi Brian, Really struggling with this. I can't seem to find the hidden fields in the code behind. I've tried to recursivly get all the controls on the form but none contain the id of the hidden field I'm after. If possible could you direct me to an example? I've tried searching but must be using the wrong terminology or can't see the wood for the trees!

Comment: Are you using `<asp:HiddenField` or `<input type="hidden"`?  If you are using web forms, use the former than you can directly refer to it.